# export 'initializeApp' (imported as 'initializeApp') was not found in 'firebase/app' (possible exports: default)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I have been building a signup authorization for an app using fire base
but whenever i use `</FirebasecontextProvider>` in route it raises an error like said in the title.

the below code is context.js

```
import { useContext, createContext, useState } from "react";

import { auth } from "../firebase/config";

export const Firebasecontext=createContext({currentuser:null});   


export function FirebaseContextProvider({children}){
 const {currentuser,setCurrentUser}=useState();
 const value={currentuser}

 return(<Firebasecontext.Provider value={{value}}>
    {children}
  </Firebasecontext.Provider>)
}

export const UserAuth=()=>{
    return useContext(Firebasecontext)
}
```

the below code is  from app.js..the error occurs when i put `<FirebaseContextProvider><FirebaseContextProvider/>`in the route

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
    
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
          
          <Route exact path="/"><Home /></Route>
          <Route path="/signup"><Signup/></Route>
       
          
    </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
   
    </div>
  );
```